# Pre-planning vs planning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The Oxford online dictionary defines "pre-plan" as to "plan in advance". But isn't that generally the point of planning - to do it in advance?

Comment: I feel obliged to point out that George Carlin had a wonderful rant about this use of the prefix *pre-* in his "Airline Announcements" sketch, citing *pre-planning* amongst *pre-heating*, *pre-boarding*, *pre-recorded* and *pre-existing*. He argues (in somewhat ruder terms) that *pre-* in these neologisms is entirely superfluous, used only to pretty up the original word in order to sound more important. "What does it mean to pre-board? You get on before you get on?"

Comment: @SáT These days for an extra fee, you can pre-board in the sense that you can board earlier than the economy-class passengers

Comment: Related: [what is the difference between “reservation” and “advance reservation”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567615), [Is there a difference between “being selected” and “being pre-selected”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169270).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is used more in the context of planning about planning. Or more explicitly, it conveys to the other person that there will be, at a minimum, another round of planning after the pre-planning to solidify the plans. I see it more as a way to differentiate with one-shot planning.

Comment: +1 - I agree. One other use I might mention is planning well in advance of when it is usually done. For example, funerals are usually planned at the time of a loved one's death. If someone planned their own funeral while they were well (to spare the bereaved), I'd call this *pre-planning*.

Comment: that's a good example @medica

Comment: ... But it wouldn't really work for 'post-planning'.

Comment: Yes, this is the only sense in which the word **should** be used, but, alas, it is all too often used as a fancy synonym for *plan* (just like *proactive* should be used for being in favour of acting, but is actually used as a fancy synonym for *active*).

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post a question on this very topic, but luckily I checked and saw this post, so I will attempt to answer it myself.

I fully agree with the OP, the act of planning is to make arrangements in advance, so
how do you plan *before* planning something? To *plan* means to prepare ahead, regardless of how much time in advance.

For example, I can plan tonight's meal in the morning or plan a week ahead, the time I set aside for making that decision is irrelevant. Do I *pre-plan* the Christmas dinner sometime in November and then properly *plan* the holiday meal a week before? I can foresee that some guests may not turn up on the day and make the necessary adjustments, but if someone informs me they have suddenly become a vegan, I am forced to modify my earlier (or original) plan by making a new one.

A user commented that one might *pre-plan* a relative's funeral before their actual demise. I would describe that action as *forward thinking* or a *prearranged* funeral. The concept of people who make *prearrangements for their retirements* is equally understood.

> [forward thinking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/forward-thinking); planning or tending to plan for the future; forward-looking.

> [AFDA](http://www.afda.org.au/faq/pre-arranged-funerals) (Australian Funeral Directors Association)
>   A **Pre-Arranged Funeral** is where a client may discuss with a Funeral Director their preferences for a type and style of funeral and the Funeral Director may record these preferences for future reference, but no formal agreement is entered into for that specific funeral.

Although I searched fairly extensively, I didn't find any references as to the origins of *pre-plan*. According to [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pre-arrange&allowed_in_frame=) *pre-arranged* and *prearranged* have existed since 1792  but there is no mention of [pre-plan](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=&search=preplan&searchmode=none).

The website *Grammarist* calls the expression a [redundancy](http://grammarist.com/redundancies/) "*...the use of two or more words that say the same thing, but we also use the term to refer to any expression in which a modifier’s meaning is contained in the word it modifies (e.g., early beginnings, merge together, return back)*"

My treasured *The Chambers Dictionary* (12th edition) argues that  *pre-plan* is one of 52 words that don't impress. I will list a few of these terms.

> While there are some words which, when used correctly, help to
>   express yourself succinctly and elegantly, there are others—intended
>   primarily to impress—that are vague, clumsy, or even unnecessary, and
>   serve only to leave your listener cold. The business world in
>   particular is a rich source of these

- **actualize** (to do)
- **architect** (verb; to build, make)
- **cascade** (to disseminate from the top down: *Please cascade this information through your teams*)
- **diarize** (to arrange a date for sth: *Let's diarize a meeting*)
- **guesstimate** (a rough guess)
- **impactful** (having impact)
- **monetize** (to make money from something: *How can we monetize our web content?*)
- **performance indicator** (a measure of success)
- **pre-plan** (to plan)
- **retask** (to give someone or something a different task)
- **value proposition** (a selling point)

In other words, *pre-plan* is a business buzz word which sounds impressive until you actually stop and think about it.

Comment: In respone to  anyone searching through EL&U archives. I have since [modified my opinion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227149/what-is-the-origin-of-pre-plan), although I still persist in thinking it is redundant, *pre-plan* is far older than I had originally thought; and it has several possible meanings.  I will in due course edit/improve on this answer :)

Comment: There’s also the connotations to consider. Something *planned* is perhaps *orchestrated*, *routine*, or even *orderly*, whereas something *preplanned* carries the stronger suggestion of a *fait accompli*.

Comment: If there is a long course involved, some of the planning must be done before the course is presented, but some may well be left for nearer the date a particular lecture say is given ('intra-planning'?) Of course, fine structure of the course (operation, etc) must be involved for 'pre-planning' to be a useful term.

Answer (score 0):

pre-planning is similar to over-exaggerate and very unique.  They are evidence of the cognitive decay of post-modern society, where discipline and complexity give way to flaccid simple-mindedness.

Answer (score 0):

'Pre-plan' is a tautology, nothing more nothing less.  'pre' means before, 'plan' means to work out a course of action or have a scheme for doing something. You cannot, by definition, plan to do something after you've done it or even while your doing it.  It's a bit like saying '7 a.m. in the morning'.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use pre-plan/ning to mean being prepared for the contingencies, predictable or unpredictable, that may occur based on the "original" plans.

For example, we may plan to bring water for ourselves for a trip to the beach with friends, but might bring extra (pre-plan) for friends who forgot to bring their own, did not bring enough for themselves, or you are not sure how thirsty you might get.

I use pre-planning as the sub-set of plans to address contingencies that are inherent in any plan.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-planning is correct. Let me explain a common use case. Pre-planning is a term that is used frequently in software development teams that work based on agile methodology. In this methodology, teams have planning meetings every two weeks to plan the upcoming two weeks. Those meetings are called `planning` meetings. But to reduce the time of planning meetings, 1-2 days before planning, a meeting is held to discuss the details of topics that are to be decided on in the planning meetings. The latter is called `pre-planning` meetings.

Comment: This is, in substance, the same as the very first answer that was posted to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Pre plan is a form of word inflation, burdening the verb with an unnecessary prefix, like pre book (unless you are booking to make a booking I suppose) and another clunker “double check”. The advertisement for a form of insurance in which you are urged to “pre plan your funeral” is laughable. You can only plan your funeral. The idea that you can pre plan it suggests there is another step… but sadly by then it will be too late.

Comment: This has been said in a previous answer, similarly lacking evidence. Abdollah mentions anecdotally a non-redundant usage, but again adds no supporting evidence.

Comment: *Double* in *double check* is not redundant: there is a difference between checking something once and checking it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:
The new teacher was about to plan her lesson for the afternoon. I told her that there was no need, since she could use one of the pre-planned lessons.

I feel in this case the use of "pre-" is justified and helpful.

Someone else planned the lesson before she planned the lesson.

Comment: I think you're right, and it's a good example, but it doesn't add any new information to the existing answer. Please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with this platform. Welcome to ELU!