# What is the origin of "pre-plan"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, terminology, business-language

Although I searched fairly extensively, I couldn't find any references as to the origins of *pre-plan*. According to [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pre-arrange&allowed_in_frame=), *pre-arranged* and *prearranged* have existed since 1792  but it fails to mention the history of [pre-plan](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=&search=preplan&searchmode=none).

Dictionary.com which is a reliable source for dates and examples of usages, doesn't even list the verb. Instead it re-directs the reader to *[plan](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pre%20plan?s=t)*

Oxford Dictionaries (which rarely provides the origins of words) says

> **[pre-plan](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pre-plan)**
>   <sub><sup>[WITH OBJECT]</sup></sub> (usually as adjective pre-planned)
>   Plan in advance:  *Safety and security of supply demand that they operate to stringent standards and create a mindset that is preconditioned towards conformity and pre-planned behaviour*

Collins Dictionary notes the one word solution:

> [**preplan**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/preplan)
>   *But then he added, `We'll let the company treat us, and I'll tell you all about how to preplan and prefinance your mother's funeral*.

- Exactly how old is this "corporate speak" expression?
- Is it *really* derived from the world of business?
- Has its meaning evolved or changed during the years?

Comment: A word like "pre-plan" (with or without the hyphen) has no "origin".  Taking a word like "plan" and adding a simple prefix like "pre" is ordinary everyday English -- it's basically the same as stringing words together.  The only "origin" is that, prior to "corporate America/UK" (ca 1900), there was little need for such a term.

Comment: @HotLicks see etymonline and the link to *prearranged* and *pre-arranged*. That has a date, and a prefix too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yep, and that (earlier) date would correspond to the use of the term "prearranged marriage", et al.  Not exactly corporate-speak.  Keep in mind that such sources are merely documenting what can be found in a sample of 0.001% of the literature of the time, with no sample at all of the spoken language.  Usages could slip through the cracks for decades, if not centuries.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm fully aware that spoken language, slang, dialect may be spoken for decades before anyone gets round to writing/recording it. But it seems odd to me that such a common word, perhaps created seventy years or so, and one that divides many people has no "official" history or record so to speak. Maybe someone on EL&U can help out a bit.

Comment: Combining a common prefix with a common word is not an earth-shaking event.  No Act of Congress is needed to do it, and there is no public notice made that it has been done.  I probably several times a week do such a combination that could be "the first" (since I *love* to combine words like that), but I wouldn't expect my uses to be documented for posterity.

Comment: It's "earth shattering", and nobody is claiming it is.

Comment: It undoubtedly comes from the use of _pre-planned_ as an adjective to designate certain phenomena. Something that was _pre-planned_ was not accidental, and was not accomplished on the spur of the moment, but rather was deliberate and intentional. The _pre-_ part of that is to distinguish a complete plan existing before action is started from the kind of plan one improvises.

Comment: @JohnLawler but the meaning of *plan* is *also* to prepare something ahead of time. Now if the planning is done minutes or even years before any decisive action is finally taken, one has in any case *planned* the event beforehand. Not to say that *pre-plan* isn't growing on me, but I still feel it is a bit redundant.

Comment: I'd love to know why this question has been downvoted.

Comment: As I said, the participial adjective is the likely source; in most verbal uses there's no reason for the prefix, so it's not one that's likely to appear ex nihilo unless there's some cultural freight it's carrying. Like business jargon.

Comment: @JohnLawler a sort of substitute for "an advance plan" as in *A pre-planned operation*? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the usual bracket shuffle: [pre-[planned operation]] => [[pre-planned] operation] => ... => [[pre-plan] [the operation]].

Comment: Used as a verb, “pre-plan” sounds potentially redundant to me as well (& the issue w/“post-plan” as a verb goes well beyond one of redundancy); but the redundancy disappears when used as a participial adjective, perhaps especially with its past participle, “pre-planned,” as mentioned by @JohnLawler, but also w/its present one, “pre-planning,” where one could logically begin w/the “pre-planning stage or process,” proceed next to the “planning stage/process” & then perhaps even on to the “post-planning stage/process” prior to the plan’s final execution. FWIW, no downvote from here, au contraire.

Comment: See also _pre-organized, pre-distributed, pre-determined, pre-eminent, pre-destined_. An apparently redundant usage is almost always a matter of intensifying or qualifying an original usage.

Comment: The older editions of Websters dictionary - http://machaut.uchicago.edu/websters - do not have the word.  I could see lot of mentions in comments to Israel formation and Balfour declaration (1926), though i dont seem to find the word actually used in the declaration.  The mid 1940s - when India got independence and Israel was formed - seems to be the 'fountainhead'.  It is to be noted that usage of 'preplanned' has overtaken 'preplanning' and 'preplan' since then (as per Google NGram).

Answer (score 3):

The two earliest instances of *preplan*/*preplanned*/*preplanning* (with or without a hyphen) that a Google Books search finds are from the pen of Robert Southey, who was Poet Laureate of England for the last thirty years of his life (from 1813 to 1843). The first instance is from a [letter by Robert Southey to the Reverend Neville White](https://books.google.com/books?id=oegpAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA409&dq=%22pre+planned%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zqnhVMewBJHkoAS014DwBA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22pre%20planned%22&f=false), dated February 19, 1824, reprinted in *Selections from the Letters of Robert Southey* (1856):

> My dear Neville,
>
> Here I am, once more at my desk, by my own fire-side. My movements were all punctually performed, as they had been **pre-planned**. I reached home on Sunday morning, without impediment or mishap of any kind, and, thank God, found all well. Some little time is required before I can fairly get into joint again, after so complete a dislocation ; and I bring back with me a formidable accumulation of letters, which followed and found me whithersoever I went, and which it was not possible for me to answer during so hurried a mode of life.

The next is a quotation from Robert Southey's "[Colloquies on the Progress and Prospects of Society](https://books.google.com/books?id=8o5IAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA618&dq=%22pre+planned%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OJ_hVM-DJZKoogT29IL4DA&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22pre%20planned%22&f=false)," in a review of that work in *Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine* (October 1829):

> *Montesinos* [a character in Southey's dialogue, speaking to Thomas More]. Like the whole fabric of our society, it [the manufacturing system in contemporaneous England] has been the growth of circumstances, not a system **pre-planned**, foreseen, and diliberately chosen. Such as it is, we have inherited it, or rather have fallen into it, and must get out of it as well as we can. We must do our best to remove its evils, and to mitigate them while they last, and to modify and reduce it till only so much remains as is indispensable for the general good.

From "[Shakespeare in Modern Thought](https://books.google.com/books?id=MmAvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA507&dq=%22pre+planned%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ApfhVK_hH5DToATz5ICYCA&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22pre%20planned%22&f=false)," in *North American Review* (October 1857):

> The events and characters of a drama may be very amusing and interesting, may be morally and spiritually edifying ; but unless they proceed from some common point of view, some pervading, centralizing principle, and so are related essentially to one another, having a common life, they do not belong to the domain of rt. There is undoubtedly, such a universal "central idea" for each living man. The dramatic poet, like a presiding deity, surveys all the details, and holds in his hands the threads of connection and relation, so that his representation is no patchwork of circumstances and capricious succession of words and deeds, but a regular and **pre-planned** figure, woven out of many different and variously colored threads, each of which has its place in the finished product, and is essential to a complete embodiment of the ideal pattern.

From "[Long Vacation](https://books.google.com/books?id=0fZTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA40&dq=%22pre+planned%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ApfhVK_hH5DToATz5ICYCA&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22pre%20planned%22&f=false)," in *London Society* (January 1868):

> Then came preparation, packing, and departure. One by one the crew broke away ; cordially we shook hands, and **pre-planned** réunions in town, at Lord's, in the Highlands, and elsewhere.

From John Scott Russell, [*Systematic Technical Education for the English People*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CB1DAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA139&dq=%22pre+planned%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ApfhVK_hH5DToATz5ICYCA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22pre%20planned%22&f=false) (1869) [the same year as the New York Court of Appeals Decision cited in bib's answer]:

> But the growing youth, who has everything to learn, and no help, how is he to find fit education and training for his work in life? For the ordinary English lad, education must be **pre-planned**, prepared, brought home to him, to his father's home, to his master's workshop. He cannot seek education. We must seek him.

The origin of the word *preplan* thus appears to rest not with an anonymous twentieth-century purveyor of business jargon, but with a nineteenth-century poet and litterateur; and other early instances of the phrase show its being taken up in the fields of literary criticism, memoir, pedagogy, and law. The modern notion of convening a preplanning meeting before the planning meeting to work out what will be covered and (perhaps) decided at the latter may be a creature of corporate or government bureaucracy; but *preplanning* itself evidently was not born in a conference room.

With a confirmed first occurrence Google Books search results of 1824, *preplan* actually beats the earliest confirmed match for the phrase "plan ahead"—which has its own problem with face-value redundancy, and which has a confirmed [first occurrence of 1848](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Uo7AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA52&dq=%22plan+ahead%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nabhVOTvH9G6ogTq5YGIBg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAzgo#v=onepage&q=%22plan%20ahead%22&f=false) in Google Books search results. I see very little change in the sense of *preplanned* from its meaning as used by Southey in the 1820s and its meaning as given by Oxford and Collins and quoted in Mari-Lou A's question.

Comment: Is *diliberately* a typo or is it in the original text?

Comment: @MariLouA: It's in the original. The link in the article title preceding the quoted excerpt takes you to the page in _Blackwood's Edinburgh Magazine_ that contains the excerpt. Nineteen times out of twenty, of course, a typo of that sort in one of my answers will have been accidentally introduced by me. I know that standard practice is to use "[sic]," but I try to provide links to the original instead.

Answer (score 2):

The term *preplan* goes back to at least the 19th century in the US. A cursory  ngram search reveals several examples from the late 1800s

In a [decision of the New York State Court of Appeals](https://books.google.com/books?id=_rlpb9io8wwC&pg=RA2-PA101&dq=%22preplan%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ArPcVO-2DMaZNsLgg5AL&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgU#v=onepage&q=%22preplan%22&f=false) from 1869, in considering a plot of a son against his mother, the Court used the phrase

> under preplanned, designed false pretenses?
>
> *and later*
>
> Legrand then had not imagined George would preplan to testify falsely

The connotation suggests *plotting*.

In a play, *[Sejanus: a tragedy](https://books.google.com/books?id=46MNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22preplan%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-a_cVNCuC8ijNsnSg8gF&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22preplan%22&f=false)* by A. Arteton, from 1876 had a character ask

> Why did not his daring soul, on being check'd, preplan that Rome should be fir'd and destroy'd

The tone here is more *foresee*

It then appears in the early 20th century in places such as the [School Journal](https://books.google.com/books?id=rfs9AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA515&dq=%22preplan%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8LDcVJD7HYW_ggTr94LQAg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATgU#v=onepage&q=%22preplan%22&f=false) from 1909

> how results are affected by the presence or absence of forethought, preplanning or fearless freedom ...

This example seems to suggest *diligent preparation*.

None of these are classic business contexts.

Comment: This is a good answer. It's a pity this question, and your answer hasn't attracted more attention. What to do? Place yet another bounty?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the question is interesting since the term seems to be internally redundant (can you post-plan?) and the derivation is puzzling. Corporate-speak was a good guess, and I still don't have a handle on how it started.

Answer (score 1):

You either plan or you don't. Planning is always before a premeditated action. 'pre-planning' is a bogus term that actually means nothing, it was made up.

Answer (score -1):

There are similar words which are often attributed to Indian English (some debate about Occidental English vs Oriental English).  Pre-plan, Pre-pone etc are such Indian variants which are often to 'emphasize'.  It is to take 'pre' vs 'post' for 'before' and 'after' and use in other English words as a qualifier or 'integrated adjective'.  For eg, you should do planning is converted to you should do 'lot of pre'planning.

Edit:

To add the link for 'prepone' - http://www.dnaindia.com/lifestyle/report-now-entire-world-can-prepone-like-indians-only-1353503

Comment: I don't believe that *pre-plan* has Indian origins. Evidence (Ngram link posted by @Frank but now deleted) seems to suggest that *pre-plan* was being used in the late 19th century.

Comment: The question is about **pre-plan**. Please search through EL&U's database and find a question which asks about *prepone*. Here: http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=prepone

Comment: I tend to think people used pre-plan like 'prepare' and 'plan'.  BTW, Ngram does not refer to usage of English word by non-Indians alone, does it?

Comment: Google Ngram I believe records all publications printed in a country. It doesn't matter who the authors were, if their work was printed/published in the US or the UK, Google will have a record. (That's my understanding).

Comment: Ngram is interesting because if we plot preplanning with five year plan, you can see similar lines almost going together and in particular 'ascent' during mid 1940s. India got independence in 1947!  Just plot with awesome, you understand preplanning is hardly in usage and even if some use it, it is a non-issue.

Comment: I've just realized but you do have enough reputation points to leave comments. Newcomers often express their opinions in Answers because they are blocked by the system to leave comments. Could you at least say what pre-plan means in India now and how its meaning has changed over the years.